# I would like to know to create a youtube like flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flash, embed

I basically want to embed a swf object and then feed different videos to it. Right now, I made a xml driven video player, however, I would have to create a new swf and xml list for each video I want to embed on my site. This is a real drag and pain. What is the procedure to make a universal player like youtube.
FYI: I can't use flow player because it uses java script and I would like the pages I make on my site to be able to share on facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at an article for the [Adobe Open Source Media Framework](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/video_osmf.html). Home site [here](http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/).

Answer (score 1):

How is the player xml based if you have to create a new swf for each video?
You have to simply send the absolute path of the flv at embed time through flashvars.